# Familys of curves in z-plane depending on 1 parameter

Tags: complex-numbers

Describe the family of curves depending on $C>0$
$$\left|\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}\right| = C $$
and 
$$arg\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}} = C $$

What I got:

let $z=x+iy, z_{1}=a+ib, z_{2}=c+id$
$$\left|\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}\right| = \frac{(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}}{(x-c)^{2}+(y-d)^{2}}=C^{2}$$ from here:
$$(1-C^{2})x^{2}-(2a-C^{2}2c)x+(1-C^{2})y^{2}-(2b-C^{2}2d)y=C^{2}d^{2}+C^{2}a^{2}-a^{2}-b^{2}$$
which I think is an equation of a circle. Is this correct? 
For the second question: I am kind of confused... I know that $arg\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}$ represents an angle $z_{1}zz_{2}$, so keeping this constant and equal to C wouldn't just be a point? But I am getting, proceeding similar way like in the first one, an equation of circle, again. But I can't see way it have to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that

$$
\left|\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}\right| = C
$$

leads to

$$
\frac{(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}}{(x-c)^{2}+(y-d)^{2}}=C^{2}
\;,
$$

but it's wrong to also equate that to

$$
\left|\frac{z-z_{1}}{z-z_{2}}\right|
$$

because it's the square of that. Yes, this is the equation of a circle; so the locus of points with constant ratio of distances to two different points is a circle.

For the second part, you're also right that this leads to a circle equation; see the [inscribed angle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem). However, note that only part of the circle fulfills the original equation; for the other part the angle is shifted by $\pi$.

Comment: Thankyou @joriki. Just may I clarify 1 point: would the $z_{1} $ and $z_{2}$ be on the circle and z in the center, because that's what would be needed for inscribed angle theorem.

Comment: sry, I got it. The three of them should be on the circle. Right?

Comment: @Mykolas: Yes. The inscribed angle theorem is just needed to show that the angle is always the same; otherwise the centre plays no role.

Comment: Thankyou a lot again @joriki

Comment: @Mykolas: You're welcome!