# I need to describe a behavior of a curve depending one one parameter in z-plane

Tags: complex-numbers

$|z^{2}-1|=\lambda$

My aprouch: taking $z=x+iy$  $$z^{2}=(x^{2}-y^{2})+i(2xy)$$
Then : $$|z^{2}-1|^{2}=x^{4}-2x^{2}y^{2}+2y^{2}-2x^{2}+y^{4}+1+4x^{2}y^{2}=\lambda^{2}$$
Now taking $x^{2}=\alpha,y^{2}=\beta$:
$$\alpha^{2}+2\alpha\beta+\beta^{2}-2\alpha+2\beta+(1-\lambda^{2})=0$$
This is equation of a parabola since the discriminant is equal to $0$
Would this be correct? And is there, maybe more "geometrical" way to see this?

Comment: You made the same mistake here as the one I pointed out in your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202953): $|z^2-1|^2=\lambda^2$ (not $|z^2-1|$).

Comment: Ups. You right. Thankyou @joriki. But is the rest correct?

Comment: The last equation looks OK, but in the middle one it should be $-2x^2y^2$.

Comment: OK. That's just typeing mistake. Is there anyway to see this geometricly directly without getting all this equations?

Comment: I don't know of one.

Comment: Ok. Thankyou one more time @joriki